# Promise with Javascript

Tags: javascript, express, promise

I'm struggling to understand Promise but it's really difficult for me.
it makes me crazy, I would appreciate your helps.

this is a code and I want "console.log(data)" after Recommend function  finished
but the result is undefined.
What should I do? 
many thanks

This is app.js

```
var _promise = function () {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        var data = getJS.Recommend(req.query.User_id)
        resolve(data)
    }).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    })

    _promise();
}})
```

this is RecommendPost.js

```
exports.Recommend =(myId)=>{
    var posts=[]
    User.find({
        User_id : myId
    }).then((result)=>{
        return User.find()
            .select('User_id')
            .where('age').equals(result[0].age)
    }).then((User_id)=>{
        return Promise.all(User_id.map((user,idx,arr)=>{
            return Count.find()
                .select('board_id')
                .where('User_id').equals(user.User_id)
        }))
    }).then((Users_id)=>{
        Users_id.forEach(items=>{
            items.forEach(post=>{
                posts.push(post.board_id)
            })
        })
    }).then(()=>{
        return getMax(posts);
    })
}
```

cf. In RecommendPost.js, the posts works synchronously

//-------- I solved this problem! as some guys said, Recommend function should return Promise. So I edited, then this worked !
this is edited code. thank you for helping me :)

This is app.js

```
var _promise = function () {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            getJS.Recommend(req.query.User_id).then((data) => {
                resolve(data);
            })
        })
    }
    _promise().then((data) => { console.log(data) });
```

this is RecommendPost.js

```
exports.Recommend =(myId)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        var posts=[]
        User.find({
            User_id : myId
        }).then((result)=>{
            return User.find()
                .select('User_id')
                .where('age').equals(result[0].age)
        }).then((User_id)=>{
            return Promise.all(User_id.map((user,idx,arr)=>{
                return Count.find()
                    .select('board_id')
                    .where('User_id').equals(user.User_id)
            }))
        }).then((Users_id)=>{
            Users_id.forEach(items=>{
                items.forEach(post=>{
                    posts.push(post.board_id)
                })
            })
        }).then(()=>{
            resolve (getMax(posts));
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a promise for a seemingly synchronous operation? Also, that (for some reason) recursive call to `_promise` is unreachable.

Comment: then how could I edit? it doesn't need to use promise? I thought it's because asynchronous  that code came out undefined.

Comment: You aren't returning a promise from `Recommend` that can be chained.

Comment: what? I don't understand T-T could you give me a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

When you call to `resolve` function is mean that the function is finish and it returns to the caller.
the data object in the `then` doesn't exist

> The Promise.resolve(value) method returns a Promise object that is
>   resolved with the given value. If the value is a promise, that promise
>   is returned; if the value is a thenable (i.e. has a "then" method),
>   the returned promise will "follow" that thenable, adopting its
>   eventual state; otherwise the returned promise will be fulfilled with
>   the value.

ES5 :

```
var _promise = function (req) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        getJS.Recommend(req.query.User_id).then((data)=>{
            console.log(data)
            resolve(data)
        },(err)=>{
            console.log(err)
            reject(err);
        })
    })
}
_promise(req);
```

ES6

```
async function _promise(req) {
   return await getJS.Recommend(req.query.User_id)
}
```

**For your edit(The entire code):**

In this case that `Recommend` function returns a promise, you don't need the `_promise` function that wraps it with another one.

and you call it direct

```
getJS.Recommend(req.query.User_id).then(
 (data) => { 
  console.log(data) 
});
```

Comment: This is an antipattern. If `getJS.Recommend` already returns a promise, then why wrap it in another?

Answer (score 0):

It might be clearer for you with `async/await` that makes asynchronous code look like synchronous:

```js
async function main() {
  var data = await getJS.Recommend(req.query.User_id); // waits till its done before going to the next line
  console.log(data);
}

// unimportant specific implementation details for live example:

const getJS = {
  Recommend(id) {
    data = "some data for user ";
    return new Promise((res) => setTimeout(() => res(data + id), 1000));
  }
}

const req = {
  query: {
    User_id: 5
  }
}

main();
```

Comment: I'm sorry that it doesn't work. :'(  still undefined

Comment: does`async/await` work for frontend too? I just know it from the NodeJs backend

Comment: @MHComputech latest browser versions support it but you should transform it to es5 compatible code with babel or typescript to support all browsers.

Comment: @choyoungkim does `getJS.Recommend` return a promise?

Answer (score -2):

Promises means it will always return something, either error or success.

if you resolve something then it will return from there. so your .then part will not execute.

so if you are using resolve and reject params in function then, use .catch method.

```
return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    var data = getJS.Recommend(req.query.User_id)
    resolve(data)
}) .catch(function (ex) { // in case of error
    console.log(ex);
})
```

Comment: actually promises can also be in a `pending` state forever.

Comment: yes, it's right. it results pending. how could I edit?